# Using Case inside the Query function

Tags: sql, google-sheets

Does anyone know if the Query function in Google Spreadsheets supports the use of Case statements?  If not, is there another method that would help produce the desired output like an If statement or Decode used in Oracle?

For example, I am querying column D which is a date:

```
=QUERY(FPA!B:Q,"SELECT Sum( Case Month(D) when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ‘JAN’, 
                       Sum( Case Month(D) when 2 then 1 else 0 end) as ‘FEB’, 
                       Sum( Case Month(D) when 3 then 1 else 0 end) as ‘MAR’",1)
```

Spreadsheet:

```
Employee   |   Start Dt   | Location
-------------------------------------
John Smith |  03-Mar-2015 | New York  
Mary Jane  |  27-Jan-2015 | Los Angeles     
Kim Wagner |  13-Feb-2015 | Chicago
```

Output:

```
Location    | JAN | FEB | MAR 
-----------------------------
New York    |     |     |   1
Chicago     |     |   1 |   
Los Angeles |   1 |     |
```

Comment: @pnuts I've added the desired output to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the starting data set.

Answer (score 0):

To mimic that result you may have to try something like

```
=ArrayFormula(query({UPPER(text(B2:B, "mmm")),B2:C}, "select Col3, count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col3 pivot Col1"))
```