# How do I use “CASE” in Google Query Language

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I’m using Google Sheets and `QUERY` function.

I want to convert strings.
eg. By using `CASE` expression in SQL like

```
CASE
    WHEN A != “” THEN “1”
    ELSE “0”
END
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Even if it has silent answers, this thread can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32387628/4636715

Answer (score 1):

well, `CASE` could be `IF` and not sure why you want to use query... try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A10<>"", 0, 1))
```

[image: 0]

or: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A10<>"", 1, 0))` for reverse

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve something similar. Solved it by combining `ArrayFormula` with the `If` function (building on [player0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54783881/6757005)):

```
=ArrayFormula(If(Query(A1:A10, "SELECT A")<>"", "1", "0"))
```

- [ArrayFormula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [If](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)
- [Working example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PUE9TLi6EA_eJPZUFr1ToB1M5pkgPvYaEwCK-8ds2jQ/edit?usp=sharing)